# How to import a Cmdlet from a DLL

Tags: powershell, dll, build, powershell-cmdlet

Is it possible to import and invoke a Cmdlet from a DLL that is not in the PATH directories?

I want to write a build script with powershell that is able to compress the results. Therefore I found [7Zip4Powershell](http://thomasfreudenberg.com/blog/archive/2013/04/07/7-zip-for-powershell.aspx) Cmdlets ([Source](https://github.com/thoemmi/7Zip4Powershell)), but I am unable to invoke them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Import-Module command to load a PowerShell module. Therefore, you should be able to use:

```
Import-Module C:\Temp\7Zip4Powershell.dll
```

Comment: When I try this I get a BadImageFormatException. Could it be because I am using Powershell 2 and 7Zip4Powershell seems to be build with .NET Framework 4.0?

Comment: Yes, it's almost certainly down to your PowerShell version. Type in `$psversiontable` and see what CLRVersion you're using - it'll be 2.0 in PowerShell 2.

Comment: When I tried it with PS 3 it worked, but I had to unblock the dll first, because it was downloaded from the internet.